# Complex Number 'inversion'

Tags: complex-analysis

I was playing around with alternative ways of proving that if $\dfrac{iz-1}{z-i}$ is real, then $z$ lies on the unit circle, excluding $i$. However, I noticed something that I'm not sure is of any significance.

**What I did:**

Factorise $i$ from the numerator.

$\dfrac{i(z+i)}{z-i}$

If this number is purely real, then $\dfrac{z+i}{z-i}$ must be purely imaginary, in other words equal to $ki$ where $k\in\mathbb{R}$

Upon re-arranging, I acquired $z=\frac{k-i}{1+ki}$, which is almost the same thing as the original expression!

**My Question**

Is there any significance to this, perhaps a property that I can use to complete the proof from here? Or is this merely a coincidence that leads to nowhere?

Comment: As Cameron said (but deleted), you're playing with a Mobius transformation. Such functions are invertible, with the inverse being another Mobius transformation. Furthermore, they are known to map circles/lines to circles/lines. This is all very fundamental in the study of complex variables. So in short, YES, there is plenty of significance to your approach.

Comment: Actually better if you do not factor out the $i.$ The M&ouml;bius transformations $$ \frac{Az + B}{Cz + D} $$ that are their own inverses are precisely those for which $A+D = 0;$ it is still necessary to demand nonzero determinant, that is $AD-BC \neq 0.$

Comment: Note that, in an answer window, correctly gives an o umlaut, lower case.